# grails 3.0.1 proxy settings

Tags: grails, proxy

I am new to Grails 3.0.1 and wonder how and where to set the correct Proxy settings. I know what my proxy configuration is - IP and port, but don't know where to place.
I am getting errors like these when trying to run grails command within my helloworld project:

```
ivo@ivotrisquel:~/grails/projects/helloworld$ grails --stacktrace
| Error Problem updating profiles from origin git repository (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: https://github.com/grails/grails-profile-repository: cannot open git-upload-pack
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:139)
    at org.grails.cli.profile.git.GitProfileRepository.fetchAndRebaseIfExpired(GitProfileRepository.groovy:140)
    at org.grails.cli.profile.git.GitProfileRepository.createOrUpdateRepository(GitProfileRepository.groovy:109)
    at org.grails.cli.profile.git.GitProfileRepository.getProfile(GitProfileRepository.groovy:56)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.initializeProfile(GrailsCli.groovy:347)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.execute(GrailsCli.groovy:192)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.main(GrailsCli.groovy:99)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: https://github.com/grails/grails-profile-repository: cannot open git-upload-pack
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.connect(TransportHttp.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.openFetch(TransportHttp.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.executeImp(FetchProcess.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.execute(FetchProcess.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.fetch(Transport.java:1115)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:130)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out github.com
    at org.eclipse.jgit.util.HttpSupport.response(HttpSupport.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.connect(TransportHttp.java:475)
    ... 11 more
| Error Problem updating profiles from origin git repository
```

Comment: could you please also add, what you have tried so far (e.g. the usual suspects of setting via JAVA/GRAILS_OPTS, is it set in http_proxy, ...)

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem and solved it adding the proxy configuration to the GRAILS_HOME/bin/grails.bat  file in the following way:

```
>set GRAILS_OPTS=%GRAILS_OPTS% -Dhttp.proxyHost=myProxy -Dhttp.proxyPort=myPort -Dhttps.proxyHost=myProxy -Dhttps.proxyPort=myPort -Dhttp.proxyUser=bob -Dhttp.proxyPassword=theBuilder
```

I believe there must be another way to configure the proxy in Grails 3.0.x but I haven't found it so far.

Regards

Comment: This has been added to the user guide https://github.com/grails/grails-doc/commit/5f1bb09b6e02d3a07fce82a74f4dff7ec6a0e618

Answer (score 3):

In linux adding the configuration

```
export GRAILS_OPTS="-Dhttp.proxyHost=myProxy -Dhttp.proxyPort=myPort -Dhttps.proxyHost=myProxy -Dhttps.proxyPort=myPort"
```

in the GRAILS_HOME/bin/grails.sh file. Resolve my problem in Netbeans 8.1

Comment: or `set GRAILS_OPTS=-Dhttp.proxyHost=myProxy -Dhttp.proxyPort=myPort -Dhttps.proxyHost=myProxy -Dhttps.proxyPort=myPort` in windows

Answer (score 2):

I adedd the following to my `~/.grails/ProxySettings.groovy` file.

```
client=['http.proxyHost':'myproxy', 'http.proxyPort':'myport', 'http.proxyUser':'myusername', 'http.proxyPassword':'mypass', 'http.nonProxyHosts':'localhost']
currentProxy='client'
```

Answer (score 2):

For GRAILS3 there is now enough documentation on how to setup proxy.

As said by @campos, in Windows you must

```
set GRAILS_OPTS=-Dhttp.proxyHost=myProxy -Dhttp.proxyPort=myPort -Dhttps.proxyHost=myProxy -Dhttps.proxyPort=myPort
```

but that makes correction only for half the way, because you also have to correct gradle engine, inserting in its gradle.properties values as below

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=proxy.yourdomain.com
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.http.proxyUser=userid
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=yourpass
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=localhost
```

There is complete explanation [here](https://github.com/grails/grails-doc/commit/5f1bb09b6e02d3a07fce82a74f4dff7ec6a0e618) and [here for gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:accessing_the_web_via_a_proxy). With all that on my Windows10 I can correctly compile and build packages behind my corporate proxy.

Answer (score 0):

After long struggle I found the solution for windows environment
The following worked for me

> set GRAILS_OPTS=-Dhttp.proxyHost=myProxy -Dhttp.proxyPort=myPort -Dhttps.proxyHost=myProxy -Dhttps.proxyPort=myPort -Dhttp.proxyUser=bob -Dhttp.proxyPassword=theBuilder